# JMeter - Status code 404 with higher user load

Tags: jmeter

I am running a load test on JMeter with 200 users. Around 10 percent of the request sent for each sampler results into failure with a status code 404 - Not found error. However, if I run my test with a load of 100 users I do not encounter 404 errors. Please advice me on what can be the issue and possible solution for this.?

Answer (score 0):

It’s a server issue only. Some applications handle server error in a kind of strange way.
So you would need to:

- analyze access logs
- add monitoring and APM to diagnose
- check error logs

Comment: Thanks.. for the info @UBIK. I am  looking into APM logs if I can deduce the real cause out of it.

Comment: If answer is ok, you should accept it and upvote so that others can trust it. Thanks